# Which validations are used for this in CakePHP?

Tags: validation, cakephp

For the below image I would like to display an error message like "Package name is alert exit".

[image]

Which validation rules applies for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use validation in your model like this:

```
$validate = array('name' => array(
   'rule' => 'isUnique'
   'message' => 'Package name is already exist.'
));
```

You can check [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#Model::Validation::isUnique).